# SQL Insert data from multiple tables in different database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert, sql-insert

I have cat table in a2 database I want to insert into id, img columns from different tables with different database

> INSERT INTO a2.cat (id, img) SELECT id FROM topshop_test.product ,
>   SELECT name FROM topshop_test.product-images ;

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look into using a `JOIN` for this:

```
INSERT INTO a1.cat (id, img)
SELECT p.id, pi.name
FROM topshop_test.product p 
    JOIN topshop_test.product-images pi ON p.id = pi.productid
```

This assumes the product-images table has a productid field that links to the product table.

Comment: p and pi is stander or I can type any characters

Comment: @FahmyFarahat -- they are just table aliases -- easier than typing the table name out.  So yes, you could change those to any values.

Comment: dose not work here the error#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-images pi ON p.id = pi.productid' at line 4

Comment: @FahmyFarahat -- You need to change pi.productid to whatever your foreign key is in that table (you didn't supply table definitions, so I had to guess).  You should have a product id field in your product-images table -- use that instead.